# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax-error

After inserting shortcode into a Wordpress theme I'm building, I received the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in
>   /home/content/70/11104970/html/wp-content/themes/theme/cait.php on
>   line 11

The bit of code in question:

```
<div class="vlog-stream">
        <?php echo do_shortcode('[ix_show_latest_yt ytid='caitbarker' width='280' height='170' autoplay='off' count_of_videos='1']'); ?>
        <p>vlog</p>
    </div><!-- end vlog-stream -->
```

The entire file can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/aXxqQSaa).

When I've received this error in the past, it was a result of either extra spaces or the use of `"` instead of `'`. I've checked and corrected both of these things and still the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you problem seems to be the quotes. You need to escape them properly or use a combination of double quotes and single quotes:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[ix_show_latest_yt ytid='caitbarker' width='280' height='170' autoplay='off' count_of_videos='1']"); ?>
```

A tip is to look at the syntax highlighting, see how it now looks correct compared to your question?

Comment: Thank you for spotting this. For some reason, I thought " wasn't allowed at all, but indeed I was incorrect.